# Prevent automatic exit on unsuccessful ActiveMQ reconnect

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms, failover

I have a small spring-boot app set up that connects to one or more Topics on ActiveMQ, which are set in the application's application.properties file on startup - and then sends these messages on to a database.

This is all working fine, but I am having some problems when trying to implement a failover - basically, the app will try to reconnect, but after a certain number of retries, the application process will just automatically exit, preventing the retry (ideally, I would like the app to just retry forever until killed manually or ActiveMQ becomes available again). I have tried explicitly setting the connection options (such as `maxReconnectAttempts`) in the connection URL (using `url.options` in application.properties) to -1/0/99999 but none of these seem to be right as the behavior is the same each time. From looking at the advice on [Apache's own reference page](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) I would also expect this behavior to be working as default too.

If anyone has any advice to force the app not to quit, I would be very grateful! The bits of my code that I think will matter is below:

```
@Configuration
public class AmqConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AmqConfig.class);
    private static final String LOG_PREFIX = "[AmqConfig] ";

    private String clientId;

    private static ArrayList<String> amqUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    private static String amqConnectionUrl;
    private static Integer numSubs;
    private static ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    DatabaseService databaseService;

    public AmqConfig (@Value("${amq.urls}") String[] amqUrl,
                      @Value("${amq.options}") String amqOptions,
                      @Value("${tocCodes}") String[] tocCodes,
                      @Value("${amq.numSubscribers}") Integer numSubs,
                      @Value("${clientId}") String clientId) throws UnknownHostException {

        Arrays.asList(amqUrl).forEach(url -> {
            amqUrls.add("tcp://" + url);
        });

        String amqServerAddress = "failover:(" + String.join(",", amqUrls) + ")";
        String options = Strings.isNullOrEmpty(amqOptions) ? "" : "?" + amqOptions;

        this.amqConnectionUrl = amqServerAddress + options;

        this.numSubs = Optional.ofNullable(numSubs).orElse(4);
        this.clientId = Strings.isNullOrEmpty(clientId) ? InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() : clientId;

        String topic = "Consumer." + this.clientId + ".VirtualTopic.Feed";

        if (tocCodes.length > 0){
            Arrays.asList(tocCodes).forEach(s -> destinations.add(topic + "_" + s));
        } else { // no TOC codes = connecting to default feed
            destinations.add(topic);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {

        LOG.info("{}Connecting to AMQ at {}", LOG_PREFIX, amqConnectionUrl);
        LOG.info("{}Using client id {}", LOG_PREFIX, clientId);
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(amqConnectionUrl);

        Connection conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        conn.setClientID(clientId);
        conn.setExceptionListener(new AmqExceptionListener());
        conn.start();

        destinations.forEach(destinationName -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < numSubs; i++) {
                    Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                    Destination destination = session.createQueue(destinationName);
                    MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
                    messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new MessageReceiver(databaseService, destinationName));
                }

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                LOG.error("{}Error setting up queue @ {}", LOG_PREFIX, destinationName);
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return connectionFactory;
    }
}


public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener, ExceptionListener {

     public static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(MessageReceiver.class);
     private static final String LOG_PREFIX = "[Message Receiver] ";

     private DatabaseService databaseService;

     public MessageReceiver(DatabaseService databaseService, String destinationName){
         this.databaseService = databaseService;
         LOG.info("{}Creating MessageReceiver for queue with destination: {}", LOG_PREFIX, destinationName);
     }

     @Override
     public void onMessage(Message message) {

         String messageText = null;

         if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
             TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;
             try {
                 messageText = tm.getText();
             } catch (JMSException e) {
                 LOG.error("{} Error getting message from AMQ", e);
             }
         } else if (message instanceof ActiveMQMessage) {
             messageText = message.toString();
         } else {
             LOG.warn("{}Unrecognised message type, cannot process", LOG_PREFIX);
             LOG.warn(message.toString());
         }

         try {
             databaseService.sendMessageNoResponse(messageText);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             LOG.error("{}Unable to acknowledge message from AMQ. Message: {}", LOG_PREFIX, messageText, e);
         }
     }
}

 public class AmqExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {

     public static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AmqExceptionListener.class);
     private static final String LOG_PREFIX = "[AmqExceptionListener ] ";

     @Override
     public void onException(JMSException e){
         LOG.error("{}Exception thrown by ActiveMQ", LOG_PREFIX, e);
     }
 }
```

The console output I get from my application is just the below (apologies, as it is not much to go off)

```
[2019-12-12 14:43:30.292] [WARN ] Transport (tcp://[address]:61616) failed , attempting to automatically reconnect: java.io.EOFException
[2019-12-12 14:43:51.098] [WARN ] Failed to connect to [tcp://[address]:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Is your app getting started correctly or you are facing this on app startup? or maybe when some node goes down?

Comment: If ActiveMQ is up when the app starts, it works fine. If it is down then the app wont start and will log that for the user. I am struggling to get some form of failover for an app that started ok, but had ActiveMQ go down while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting Question!

Configuring the maxReconnectAttempts=-1 will cause the connection attempts to be retried forever, but what I feel the problem here are as follows:

1. You are trying to connect to ActiveMQ while creating the Bean at App
   startup, If ActiveMQ is not running when APP is starting up, the
   Bean creation would retry the connection attempts forever causing a
   timeout and not letting the APP to start.
2. Also when the ActiveMQ stops running midway you are not reattempting the connection as it is done inside @Bean and will only happen on APP startup

Hence the Connection shouldn't happen at Bean creation time, but maybe it can be done after the APP is up (maybe inside a @PostConstruct block)

These are just the pointers, You need to take it forward

Hope this helps!

Good luck!